# tmp36 soic, doesn't work, but the to92 version does, am I missing something obvious?

Tags: sensor, temperature, soic

I am using a tmp36 temperature sensor to measure temperature (with an attiny 85), when I put 5V across the GND and Vs pins of the to92 model the Vout is not 0 (I can't remember the exact value now but perhaps 0.7 or similar).

I have been trying to make a surface mount board and the Vout value using the SOIC version of the tmp36 temperature sensor is only a few mV (or sometimes 0).  I thought maybe I had killed the chips when soldering them but I just tried one before it was soldered and it is giving Vout of 0V.  I also checked all the other pins in case I had the wrong Vout pin and they were all 0. Is there something obvious I am doing wrong, or could I have gotten fake chips? (bought from two different suppliers though)... will go and check a few more now.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you have the /SHUTDOWN line pulled high? The TO92 version doesn’t have this pin.

Comment: Also, show your layout.

Comment: No, I haven't connected anything to shutdown.  The only connections I have are Vs = 5v, GND = 0V and then using a multimeter to measure between GND and Vout

Comment: do I need to pull the shutdown line high? ....

Comment: @RussellBorogove thanks!!! I checked the datasheet which said to pull the shutdown line high and now it's reading 0.7V. Thanks very much. If you want to add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOIC and SOT-23 packages for this part offer a “shutdown” state in which it consumes almost no current. The /SHUTDOWN line controls this mode. For normal operation, /SHUTDOWN must be held high — tying it to the positive voltage supply should work.

The TO-92 version of the part doesn’t have this signal; it is always running as long as it’s powered.

Many modern parts have features like this as power management for small portable devices has become a priority.